# ember app kit: some testing functions not defined

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-app-kit, ember-testing

Building my first ember app based on ember app kit.

I wanted to test the current route after transition - and found [just what I need](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_currentPath) in ember docs - `currentRouteName`, `currentURL` and `currentPath` helper functions.

However, if I use these functions i get a `"ReferencError: currentRouteName is not defined"`.

I stumbled upon [this pull request](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/pull/363/) that I suppose has the initial implementation of the same thing - but was closed in favor of adding this functionality to ember proper... For the time being, I copied the code from this PR and it does indeed get picked up and pass my tests.

**Question:** how can I utilize all the functions defined in my copy of ember.js in testing?
These route helper functions are defined alongside with `visit` and `click` functions, which my tests seem to pick up without issue. Or, are my tests picking these functions up from somewhere else?

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Hey @kingpin2k! Using EAK - in my bower.json I have `"ember": "~1.3.0-beta.4"`, and when I look in `vendor/ember/ember.js` it is version 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those methods weren't added as global helpers until 1.5, so they are only available in the canary builds as of writing this.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/2/edit

Comment: Ahh, so exposing it globally is done with `helper('currentRouteName', currentRouteName);` and so forth. That makes sense. Thank you for hunting it down!

Comment: Also looks like they are conditionally included in [1.4 beta](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0-beta.5/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L322-L379) - although not to be seen (yet) in builds.emberjs.com...

Comment: yup indeed, I saw they were featured in, but I'm not sure if they are going to build it in it.